# Verify my solution/attempt for the following complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Evaluate the following:

$\int_{C} |z|^2dz$,

where $C$ is the curve parametrize by $z(t) = t^2 + it^2,\ \ 0\leq t\leq 2\pi$

My attempt:

let $z = x + yi$, then by parametrization $x(t) = t,\ \ y(t) = t^2$

$f(z) = |z|^2 = z\bar{z}=x^2 + y^2,$ thus $f(z(t)) = (t^2 + t^4)$

$\dot{z}(t) = 1 + 2it$

Now we just pluck all these into the integral formula to derive at an answer.

So, I wanted to ask is my attempt right ?

If no, do point out my mistakes.

Comment: You have it.  Well done

Comment: Only a typo with parametrizition $C$.